# Induction heater mosfet arc

Tags: mosfet, high-voltage, induction, arc

I am building an induction heater and connected everything up. Once I connected the circuit the first time I tripped the breaker. The main breaker was only a 20Amp coming from the wall. I realized I needed a bigger breaker running off 120 so Switched to a larger breaker that wouldn't trip from the mains. I connected it up and the circuit arced and blew my mosfet. I then tried re wiring in case i messed something up. Note I also used a different mosfet because I didnt have the an extra in the circuit listed. Once I started it it arced again. Is something wrong with the circuit or is it how I am wiring it up? been doing some research and maybe I am not using high enough gauged wire to pull current. I am at a loss on what to do now. Any help would be appreciated.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Turn your schematic through 90 degrees so it's readable

Comment: Disconnect high power voltage from halfbridge and use only auciliary supply for test. Is It isolated? if Yes,  then check low side Gate waveform with oscilloscope and connect lab power supply (35V) in the place of high power voltage to halfBridge. Then check both waveforms. Note: after burning mosfets chip is probably also damaged. If You want to go cheap,  try zvs. It doeasnt need a chip and works off low voltage. Also - is this circuit on a breadboard? You're kidding? NEWER use breadbord when dealing with high power devices. Instead use piece of clear pcb and cut traces using knife or drill

Comment: Also D5 is messed up - It should be form Gate to source. (anode to source ) in this case chip is 100% damaged. For such project It is good idea to have whole bag of cheap chinese components and when IT works, change to genuine. I can not See snubbers across Your mosfets - add them.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Switched to a larger breaker"?

Comment: @fifi_22 believe that the D5 is why I was getting the spark right there. I will have to switch it and see. I switched to some cheaper mosfets after i blew this one. Snubbers I'll definitely add those in. I switch D5 and run it with my other mosfets and see what happens.

Comment: @brhans Larger breaker my Mains breaker was a 20 AMP running on the side of the wall. So I switched to a wall that had a larger breaker on it.

Comment: @fifi_22 The Bread board is only on the driver for the IR2153. I dont have an oscilloscope or I would do that. I need to invest in one I just haven't yet. Yes the Mosfet is definitely no good now. That is a good idea with the PCB though I will have to do that. I have bought some of the cheap zvs online before but I need something with a high frequency right around the 300kHz range so I built this one.

Comment: @Son of ol - also replace IR2153 - It burns always when mosfets does. I also started without oscilloscope, but now I See how much more can one learn having It. IT could work on breadborad, but I would not waste time doing It. Especially Gate drive traces should be as short as possible. Check out projects from danyk.cz (not mine) - He done similar circuit.

Comment: @fifi_22 I can see that I will have to invest in one. Would help a ton. I will go through and check everything out and make sure its good. I never thought about the IR2153 though I will do that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: check D2 It should be ultrafast Type (UF4007 not 1N4007) It's nice when mosfets have 10k pull down

Comment: Breadboard is utterly unsuitable as fifi suggests.

Comment: @fifi_22 I will check that D2 I connected up some  cheap Mosfets and switched the D5 around doesnt spark out now so thats good. Now not switching I need to order some more parts again. I have a El7212c driver but need to check the specks to see about connecting it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I will switch that breadboard out and go with the PVC like fifi_22 suggested.

Comment: @Son of ol - what about a build?

Comment: @fifi_22 The heat sink attached to the RHRG75120 was connecting to both causing a short through it. However I fixed that and still not working right. I did order an oscilloscope seeing how it was black Friday. Is one that connects to the computer so we will see how well that works. When i first tried it the circuit was not filling the caps and osculating. I reviewed and than decided to connect the ground from the 15V converter to the larger bridge rectifier. It than seemed to work but the mosfets were getting so hot that they blew. So maybe larger heat sink or perhaps mosfet that can handle it

Comment: @fifi_22 I was reviewing of using wide band gap sic. I have found a few through different companies may go with infineon. They have test boards and drivers to go with the units that are all sic mosfets. Able to handle the high frequency and high current and voltage. I am trying to stay around 8kw with the unit. So for now kinda back to square one unless i get the test board through them and the sic transistors and drivers. Haven't made that decision yet.

Comment: 8kw is huge power, 3 phase supply may be required. I'm looking forward for the project!